# Extracting the second word from a string variable

Tags: bash, string, variable

I have a string `"rtcpOnNbActive                       true"` stored in a variable `x`. I want to extract "true" as substring and store in a variable. How can I do this?

Comment: Will there always be a space in `x` just before the substring you want to extract?

Answer (score 43):

Try this way:

```
y=$(echo $x | awk '{print $2}')
echo $y
```

- `echo $x` display the value of `x`.
- `awk '{print $2}'` prints the second field of the previously displayed `x`.
- `$(`...`)` hold the output and let assign it to `y`.

Comment: `echo $x` is **not** _display the value of `x`_. `printf '%s\n' "$x"` would be.

Comment: `awk '{print $2}'` prints the second field **of each line** of the previously displayed `x`.

Answer (score 13):

Assuming that there's at least one space before the substring you wish to extract (and that the substring does not contain any spaces), you can do this with a simple parameter expansion:

```
x="rtcpOnNbActive     true"
y="${x##* }"
echo "[$y]"
```

**output**

```
[true]
```

Comment: `echo` is not portable for anything other than a literal string that doesn't start with `-` and doesn't contain any escape sequences. Its behavior varies even for the bash builtin, depending on how it was compiled, and whether `XPG_ECHO` is set. Assuming the string contains no escape sequences, this should be fine, but `printf '[%s]\n' "$y"` is still better.

Comment: @nyuszika7h: Good point, and after having read Stéphane Chazelas say similar things here and in other recent questions I really ought to break my habit of using `echo` to display the value of variables, even in "throw-away" examples like this.

Answer (score 10):

It's possible to use bash arrays for that, just place your `str` inside parenthesis. e.g.:

```bsh
arr=("first second third")
echo ${arr[1]}

str="first second third"
arr1=($str)
echo ${arr1[1]}
```

Comment: This is the best approach thanks its very simple and not an errorpron.

Comment: **The only sane solution.** Every other solution either invokes external third-party commands that may not necessarily be available or behave as expected under the current platform (e.g., `awk`) *or* performs fragile string-munging guaranteed to fail in obvious corner cases (e.g., `echo "${x##* }"`).

Answer (score 5):

you can use awk:

```
echo "rtcpOnNbActive         true" | awk '{print $NF}'
true
```

`NF` number of field in the current record

using sed:

```
echo "rtcpOnNbActive         true" | sed 's/.* //g'
true
```

using string expression:

```
 a="rtcpOnNbActive         true"
 echo ${a##* }
 true
```

using grep:

```
 echo "rtcpOnNbActive         true" | grep -Eo "[a-z]+$"
 true
```

-o is gives only exact match, `[a-z]+` will match letter from a-z and `$` means at end

Comment: Don't post content of [other answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/174039/72456) for yours in the same question, please.

Comment: what others answers????

Comment: he can save it in variable its not a big deal here

Comment: `echo` is not portable for anything other than a literal string that doesn't start with `-` and doesn't contain any escape sequences. Its behavior varies even for the bash builtin, depending on how it was compiled, and whether `XPG_ECHO` is set. Also, you should **always** double quote variable expansions and command substitution (with certain exceptions, where it's not necessary but it doesn't do any harm either). With a string like the OP's, this should be fine, but if you want to make sure `printf '%s\n' "${a##* }"` would be better.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the `read` built-in

```
read -r _ y <<<"$x"
printf "%s\n" "$y"
true
```

Comment: why involve `read`? It isn't `read` that does the split - it is `$IFS`. For some reason a lot of people consider it ok to split w/ `$IFS` *only* when `read` is involved. You can just do: `set -f; IFS=' '; printf %.0s%s $x` or whatever. In any case - you need to specify `$IFS`'s value here.

Comment: @mikeserv, it's `read` doing the splitting using `IFS`, check the [documentation](http://ss64.com/bash/read.html). The main advantage with using read is that it sets variables (which is an OP requirement) and given that it can split strings and populate an array, is good for extracting arbitrary fields from a string. Additionally, I am assuming default `IFS` here, but it's easy enough to set if needed, `IFS=$' \n\t' read -r _ y <<<"$x"` will do the trick

Comment: no, its not. `read` assigns, `$IFS` splits. if you want to populate an array, use `set` - you dont need the artificial here-string nonsense in that case. `unset IFS` gets default $IFS behavior.

Answer (score 1):

Word splitting in bash can be accomplished very succinctly with `set` builtin.

```
str="rtcpOnNbActive                       true"
# Expand positional parameters with arguments
set -- $str
# Now $1=rtcpOnNbActive and $2=true
```

This can be extended to a host of scenarios by altering value of `IFS` variable, e.g:

```
ip_address="10.0.0.138"
IFS=.
set -- $ip_address
# $1=10, $2=0, $3=0, $4=138
```

Answer (score -1):

Pretty straightforward.

```
x="rtcpOnNbActive                       true"
y=${x* }
```

The ${x*.} removes everything from the space forward and then assigns that value to y.

Very similar to what Hackaholic listed above, but a little more succinct.